# links from subdomain get redirected to other domains

Tags: redirection, domain-access, subsites

i have setup domain access on drupal 7 ... everything seems to be working fine ...
today i encountered a problem ...
some links in subdomains (sub1.domain.com/link) gets redirected to either another subdomain or the main domain (sub2.domain.com/link OR domain.com/link)

subdomains in my system are kind of sub systems of the main domain with everything shared ...

this only happens when i'm logged in with a subdomain admin user ... everything works fine with user 1 ...

i dont have $base_url in settings (only 1 global setting file)... 
i enabled to redirect www.domain to domain in htaccess ...

so have anybody seen this before ? what sould i do ?
i cant think of anything :(  ...